# Best way to switch do..while loops in a function?

Tags: c, loops, gcc, do-while

This is for C language only, still learning...

Say we have some sort of function code here containing 2 `do..while` loops:

```
int loops()
{
    do //Execute this loop first then never again (instead, use second loop)
    {
        /*do something*/
    } while(condition);

    do
    {
        /*do something*/
    } while(condition);

    return;
}
```

What's your best method to run the first `do..while` loop at **FIRST RUN**, and when we come back to this function, always run the **second** `do..while` loop?

Comment: A function parameter?

Comment: Are you sure you have the same function here? wouldn't be better have two functions?

Comment: Although AntonH's answer is very good for addressing the problem, it's more likely that you should reconsider your approach entirely as this is not something needed very often

Comment: @RyanHaining, I've included my code below his comment, if you can take a look. I don't know if there's a better way to do what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **function parametre**:

```
int loops (int loopNumber) {...}
```

Or have **2 different functions**.

If you want to use the same function, the way I'ld do it is to declare a **static variable** to check if the function has been called previously:

```
int loops()
{
    static int var = 0;
    int returnVal = 0;

    if (!var) {
        do //Execute this loop first then never again (instead, use second loop)
        {
            /*do something*/
        } while(condition);
        var = 1;
    } else {
        do
        {
            /*do something*/
        } while(condition);
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

You can also do it with a **global variable**, and the code changes very little:

```
int var = 0;

int loops()
{
    int returnVal = 0;

    if (!var) {
        do //Execute this loop first then never again (instead, use second loop)
        {
            /*do something*/
        } while(condition);
        var = 1;
    } else {
        do
        {
            /*do something*/
        } while(condition);
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: an 'int' function should not just 'return;' ;)

Comment: @Andro47 True. But I was copying his code, and I don't know what he wants to return. I'll put in a value, just to make clean(-ish) code :)

Comment: I'd also use a static variable (it isolates knowledge of the loop details within the function, whereas a parameter or global exports the knowledge unnecessarily).

But you might be able to combine the two loops into one (if they may do the same thing).

Comment: +1 for the second option.  note that this makes the function **not thread safe** unless you're sure it's called the first time when there is only one thread

Comment: @RyanHaining I tried to keep the answer very generic, because we have no idea of the rest of the code. Thanks for remarking about the thread safeness.

Comment: @AntonH I would have posted the same answer myself, but the outward effects are worth noting of course.

Comment: Forgot to add that I need to use a `do-while` loop as it's part of my assignment instruction..

Comment: @PotatoUser No problem :) Good luck with your project. Also, don't forget to accept my answer :)